# Change jquery animate to manually control function

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I want to change jquery animate function, to a function which would let me control everything manualy. Currently code increases multiple numbers with delay. Here's the code (https://jsfiddle.net/6mrLv1ma/8/):

```js
var ammount = 10;
var duration = 0.5;
var delay = (1-duration)/ammount; // 0.05

curDelay = 0;
for(var i=0;i<ammount;i++) {
 $( "#container" ).append("<div id='output"+i+"'>0</div>");
  setTimeout(
   (function(i) {
    return function() {
     animate(i, duration);
    }
   })(i, duration),curDelay*1000);
  curDelay += delay;
}

function animate(i, duration){
 $({value: 0}).animate({value: 1}, {
  duration: duration*1000,
  step: function() { 
     var placement = "output"+i;
   document.getElementById(placement).innerHTML = this.value;
  }
 })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Here's graph how it's working:

[image]

So if currentProc = 0.2, the output should be something like this:

```
0.3
0.16
0.07
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I already started but need help with the formula(https://jsfiddle.net/18kd85hn/1/):

```js
var ammount = 10;
var duration = 0.5;
var delay = (1-duration)/ammount; // 0.05

function myFunction(currentProc){ // currentProc value 0 - 1
 var values = [];
 for(var i = 0; i<ammount;i++){
  var currentPos = i*delay; // formula
   
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br>"+currentPos;
 }
}

myFunction(0.2)
```

```html
<div id="output">output:</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using jquery `animate` to increment a number?!?

Comment: I dont know, i just like it :)

Comment: What would you suggest Jamiec to use instead?

Comment: I would suggest the add operator `+`

Answer (score 0):

Got it (https://jsfiddle.net/18kd85hn/7/)

```
var value = 1-(i*delay+duration-currentProc)/duration;

if (value<0){value =0}
if (value>1){value =1}
```

And replaced jquery animate - https://jsfiddle.net/18kd85hn/8/